# My links to articles on WotC's site are broken with the 2014 site update. Where can I find the same content?

Tags: online-resources, wizards-of-the-coast

In 2014, Wizards of the Coast gave their D&D site a massive overhaul. As is WotC's tradition, all of the links are now broken and 404ing.

So now I have a link to the errata archive which doesn't work:

http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updatesarchive

What can I do about it?